# photo slider

Tags: javascript, slider, photo

random question,,...but does anyone know what photo slider is being used here?

http://www.rolandgarros.com/en_FR/index.html

or here:

http://www.theglobeandmail.com/in-photos/best-from-the-past-24-hours/article1169782/

I'm assuming neither was developed in house...(i tried looking at the source but couldn't find any clues)

Andrew

Answer (score 2):

They are using a carousel widget. Try using jCarousel built on JQuery. Or try the jCarousel lite. Even a simple search for carousel components will give you enough pointers to make such slide shows.